# Custom gradle script plugin written in kotlin dsl causing error

Tags: eclipse, gradle, kotlin, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to setup a multi-project setup with gradle and trying to generate eclipse projects with `eclipse` IDE plugin.

Below is my structure.

```
rootDir/
|---buildSrc/
    |---src/
        |---main/
            |---gradle/
                |---eclipse.gradle.kts
    |---build.gradle.kts
|---app/
    |---build.gradle.kts
|---models/
    |---build.gradle.kts
|---services/
    |---build.gradle.kts
|---build.gradle.kts
|---settings.gradle.kts
```

Below are the contents of specific files, e.g. `settings.gradle.kts` and `build.gradle.kts`

**settings.gradle.kts**

```
rootProject.name = "platform"
include("app", "models", "services")
```

**rootDir/build.gradle.kts**

```
...

val buildSrc by extra("$rootDir/buildSrc")

configure(subprojects) {
    apply(from = "$buildSrc/src/main/gradle/eclipse.gradle.kts")
}
```

**rootDir/buildSrc/src/main/gradle/eclipse.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    eclipse
}

eclipse {
    project {
        println("Running inside eclipse closure for $name")   
    }
}
```

When I run `./gradlew` I am getting below error:

```
Expression 'eclipse' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\work\sources\repos\platform\buildSrc\src\main\gradle\eclipse.gradle.kts' line: 5

* What went wrong:
Script compilation errors:

  Line 5: eclipse {
          ^ Expression 'eclipse' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found

  Line 5: eclipse {
          ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
              public val PluginDependenciesSpec.eclipse: PluginDependencySpec defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

  Line 6:     project {
                      ^ Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> Unit but String! was expected

3 errors
```

However, when I do below ***changes***, it works without errors

*rootDir/buildSrc/src/main/gradle/eclipse.gradle* **replace `eclipse.gradle.kts` file with `eclipse.gradle` and make changes as per *groovy DSL***

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
eclipse {
    project {
        println("Running inside eclipse closure for $name")   
    }
}
```

**refer correct file in *rootDir/build.gradle.kts***

```
...

val buildSrc by extra("$rootDir/buildSrc")

configure(subprojects) {
    apply(from = "$buildSrc/src/main/gradle/eclipse.gradle")
}
```

**Is having a `kotlin` file in `gradle` directory in `rootDir/buildSrc/src/main/gradle` (the custom script plugin) causing this issue? If so, is there any way to write a custom script plugin - not binary plugin - in kotlin dsl?**

I have tried putting kotlin script in `rootDir/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/eclipse.gradle.kts` but this does not helps.

Any help would be appreciable.